# Distributed session handling

Tags: java, session, tomcat, spring-security, session-state

We have a application running on Amazon ec2 which is highly scalable.
Currently, the user session is maintained per instance(Sticky session). We use tomcat. If the node goes down, the users from downed node will be redirected to actively running nodes thus triggering re-authentication.

We want to move to distributed session, thus exploring different options.
What I am looking for is, distributed session management which should be highly scalable and fault-tolerant.

Comment: There's no actual question.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you don't want your session lost when the node is going down?
You can try JDBC Session Persistence approach, to store the session to database.
You can do this in tomcat.

Comment: Yes, We don't want to loose the session if node goes down. I'm not sure if JDBC persistence approach would work for us as our application should be highly scalable. Something I am looking at currently is Apache Shiro.